# Как ускорить удаление букв из строки до и после символа?

Tags: delphi

У меня получилось вот такой код - сделать. Работает, но медленно, даже на файле в 1 мегабайт - 10 минут обработки:

Как правильно оптимизировать ?

```
procedure Working(_L1, _L2: TStrings; Mode: boolean);
var i, j: integer;
    s: String;
begin
  for i := 0 to _L1.Count - 1 do
   begin
     if Mode then s := _L1.Names[i] else s := _L1.ValueFromIndex[i];
     for j := 0 to _L2.Count - 1 do
      s := StringReplace(s, _L2.Strings[j], '', [rfReplaceAll]);
     if Mode
      then _L1.Strings[i] := Format('%s=%s', [s, _L1.ValueFromIndex[i]])
      else _L1.Strings[i] := Format('%s=%s', [_L1.Names[i], s]);
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Files_1: TextFile;
S: string;
mas: array of string;
Found: Boolean;
i: integer;
Sl: TStringList;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
     AssignFile(Files_1, OpenDialog1.FileName);
     reset(Files_1);
     end;

  sl:=TStringList.Create;
 while not Eof(Files_1) do
  begin
  ReadLn(Files_1, S);


   if sl.Count > 0 then Working(sl, Memo3.Lines, true);
   if sl.Count > 0 then Working(sL, Memo4.Lines, false);
    sL.Add(s);

   end;
  sl.SaveToFile(ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\ Text_File_Save.txt');
CloseFile(Files_1);
end;
```

Comment: Не используйте `Names` и `Values`. Вам же уже советовали вручную делить строки по символу `=`.

Comment: @Igor, Благодарен за отзыв. То есть по сути дела процедура Working бесполезна ?

Comment: Нет, она полезна. Только у нее внутри должен быть другой код ).

Comment: @Igor, Вот тут и я застрял. К сожалению. Намного другой или тот же но с правками ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В коде вопроса основная проблема - ошибка в логике. В процедуру `Working` в цикле передается постоянно растущий список `sL`.

```
if not OpenDialog1.Execute then
  exit;

delBefore := TStringList.Create;
defBefore.Assign(Memo3.Lines);
delAfter := TStringList.Create;
del.After.Assign(Memo4.Lines);

AssignFile(fIn, OpenDialog1.FileName);
Reset(fIn);
AssignFile(fOut, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\Text_File_Save.txt');
Rewrite(fOut);

while not EOF(fIn) do
begin
  ReadLine(fIn, s);
  index := Pos('=', s);
  before := Copy(s, 1, index - 1);
  after := Copy(s, index + 1, Length(s) - index); 
  for i := 0 to delBefore.Count - 1 do
    before := StringReplace(before, delBefore[i], '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  for i := 0 to delAfter.Count - 1 do
    after := StringReplace(after, delAfter[i], '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  WriteLn(fOut, before, '=', after);
end;

CloseFile(fOut);
CloseFile(fIn);

delAfter.Free;
delBefore.Free;
```

Добавьте нужные переменные в `var`.

Обратите внимание на `delBefore` и `delAfter`. Взаимодействие со строками `TMemo`, если мне не изменяет память, связано с посылкой сообщений контролу, и потому работает очень медленно.

Comment: Спасибо!, только разобрался. Параметры назначил правильно и все заработало. Ваш код в раз 100 быстрее работает. Спасибо- Igor!

Comment: @Denders В коде вопроса основная проблема - ошибка в логике. В процедуру `Working` в цикле передается постоянно растущий список `sL`.

Comment: То есть чем больше файл тем и больше цикл (это я про свой код) и по сути дела тем медленней работает программа ?

Comment: @Denders Да. Всего будет обработано не `N` строк, а `(N^2)/2`.

Comment: Теперь я понял, спасибо за профессиональный ответ - Igor.

Comment: @Denders Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Comment: Igor с полуслова понимает проблемы "птенцов Татьянова гнезда" ;)